# Need a better way to put Talend Studio on GCE Linux Desktop

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine, talend

Over the last few days I got vnc to a GCE Linux vm working.  Moral of the story: forget gnome, go with xfce. 
Got Google Chrome installed from command line.  I'm attempting to install Talend Open Studio on the vm, but navigating the website is miserable via vnc. 
Has anyone figured a way to apt-get install TalendStudio?  I don't think it exists so looking for the closest to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse and download TOS to the physical machine as where the VM resides . Then, you could use SCP / SFTP to transfer the TOS file to the VM .

Some VM packages allow sharing a folder between the physical machine and VMs. That would also allow easy transfer of the file to the VM.